# if/else in Scala: Illegal start of simple expression/Il

Tags: scala

These are the errors:

```
scala.scala:13: error: not found: value listaFibonaccisAux
  listaFibonaccisAux int 0
  ^
scala.scala:4: error: illegal start of simple expression
  if (int>fibby) fibby :: (listaFibonaccisAux int (n+1))
  ^
scala.scala:1: error: illegal start of definition
  else List()
  ^
scala.scala:1: error: eof expected but '}' found.
  }
  ^
```

And here's my code, the errors seem to refer to the simple `if/else` statements, I already tried wrapping and unwrapping stuff in parens, but it did not help:

```
def listaFibonaccis (int:Int):List[Int]=
  {
  listaFibonaccisAux (int, 0)
  }

def listaFibonaccisAux (int:Int, n:Int):List[Int]=
  {
  var fibby = fib n
  if (int> fibby)
    fibby :: (listaFibonaccisAux (int, (n+1)))
  else 
    List()
  }

def fib( n : Int) : Int = n match 
  {
   case 0 | 1 => n
   case _ => fib( n-1 ) + fib( n-2 )
  }
```

`fib` finds a number `n` in the fibonacci sequence

`listaFibonaccisAux` creates a list of fibonacci numbers using fib, and stops when the numbers get bigger than int

`listaFibonaccis` is just a simple wrapper to call the other one with the 0 to start it

it's a plain `if/else` statement giving me trouble, and that's sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about the `if`/`else` because it doesn't think the line before has ended properly.

Try this: `fib(n)`

While "infix" (space notation) is sometimes handy...

`instance.method(arg)` into `instance method arg`

...it can't be applied as you've tried to use it.

Comment: Figuring out where Scala needs parens and where it does not is driving me crazy, thank you this worked.

Comment: It's usually best to just avoid infix until you have a feel for it, and then only in the simplest, most obvious, situations.

Comment: One can never use infix on a normal function call - it needs a member function. It is called "infix" because the function name is placed in between of left and right side.